# Content on WordPress-Avada Website Does Not Display

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

I updated a website 6 months ago using Avada and everything worked fine until the this week. Here is the link, https://nrccooperative.org. If you look at the page content of every page you will see the name of the page at the top of the content area and a "read more" link on the right-side of the page. None of the Avada elements are showing up. When I create a new static page without Avada elements it does the exact same thing. This tells me Avada is not the issue. I've deactivated each plugin-in one-by-one to see which plugin (if any) is causing the problem. None of them fix the issue. Seems to be a WordPress bug or something. Has anyone seen this?

Here is the error.log,

[Sat Oct 23 07:22:24.830224 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24691:tid 3835942663936] [client 173.236.171.14:43106] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds, referer: https://nrccooperative.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1634998823.5726699829101562500000
[Sat Oct 23 07:22:24.830351 2021] [core:error] [pid 24691:tid 3835942663936] [client 173.236.171.14:43106] End of script output before headers: wp-cron.php, referer: https://nrccooperative.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1634998823.5726699829101562500000
[Sat Oct 23 07:22:34.583499 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24648:tid 3836269782784] (32)Broken pipe: [client 173.236.171.14:44340] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: https://nrccooperative.org/2021/05/20/hannah-jaicks/
[Sat Oct 23 15:39:36.734376 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24648:tid 3836442236672] (32)Broken pipe: [client 52.158.174.224:55296] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 16:47:17.930488 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836345317120] (32)Broken pipe: [client 52.158.174.228:41472] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 18:37:57.190724 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836219426560] (32)Broken pipe: [client 173.236.171.14:55942] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, referer: https://nrccooperative.org/2021/05/20/morgan-graham/
[Sat Oct 23 18:56:09.056513 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836328531712] (32)Broken pipe: [client 13.89.137.131:47872] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 21:12:56.200971 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836211033856] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 18.191.40.22:36272] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 21:12:57.522251 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836442236672] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 18.191.40.22:36294] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 21:13:02.005553 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24479:tid 3836294960896] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 18.191.40.22:36428] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Sat Oct 23 21:13:02.887130 2021] [fcgid:warn] [pid 24518:tid 3836467414784] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 18.191.40.22:36470] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

I tried what they suggested here in the .htaccess file, but nothing is working right now.

https://techjourney.net/connection-reset-by-peer-mod_fcgid-ap_pass_brigade-failed-in-handle_request_ipc-function/

Comment: Did you check your error logs? Another one is set wp_debug to true in your wp-config file to see what error is generated...

Comment: I added the error.log above. I've seen multiple suggestions on this but have not been successful yet. Some suggest adding "FcgidBusyTimeout 3600" and others say to modify the memory_limit, etc. But nothing is working so far.

Comment: Did you increase the memory_limit (because this can be a problem)? And i see the website is online with content, correct?